# Opening an uploaded csv file

Tags: python, csv, pyramid

I am failing to open this uploaded csv file. When I use a file from the pc directory it works fine but when I upload it from an html form I get this error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

When trying to read from uploaded csv file

```
    domain_file =  request.POST['csv'].file
    file = open(domain_file, "r")
    csv_file = csv.reader(file,  delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
```

This works fine when am using a file from pc

```
    file = open('/Desktop/csv.csv', "r")
    csv_file = csv.reader( file,  delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `file` contains a file object, not a path. Use the `filename` property instead: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/

Maybe something like this:

```
domain_file = request.files['csv']
if domain_file and allowed_file(domain_file.filename):
    file = open(domain_file, 'r')
    #...
```

Also see http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.files

Comment: Thanks Andre was asking how i could implement ur answer in pyramid because i end up with nameerror:Allowed_file not defined.

Comment: Please see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/#a-gentle-introduction for a sample implementation of `allowed_file`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this you'll be able to iterate through the data in the csv line by line shown in a dict.

```
import csv
csv_contents = request.POST['csv'].value.decode('utf-8')
file = csv_contents.splitlines()
data = csv.DictReader(file)
```